# Razor Editor not working for some projects in solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I am creating a CMS using MVC 4 and the Razor Syntax and have a strange problem.
In the main project everything is working fine, but I have some additional projects in the solution (also MVC 4 projects) which are extensions to the main project (loaded at runtime) which also have their own views/layouts.

Now in these additional projects the razor editor does eighter highlight as it should, but underlining everything as missing (like the Html helper) or it does not work at all:
[image: Missing]
or
[image: Not working]

**Does anyone have an idea why?** The files are open with the Razor editor via "Open With..." to be shure the Razor editor is used.

Comment: close visual studio, and Clear asp.net temprary files and restart VS.

Comment: Where/How can I do that? Or do you mean everything which gets builded in the solution/project folder?

Comment: C>Windows>microsoft.net>framework>{versiyon}>Temproray asp.net files

Comment: Sorry, did not help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem:
I configured the build to directly build to the plugin folder of my Main Project for easy debugging and it seems the razor editor does not like that. As soon as I set the output back to "bin\" it works again.
I will now create post build steps to do the copy...

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add a dummy `web.config` file to the root of your class library with the following contents in order to fool Visual Studio's Intellisense in Razor files (taken from [`this blog post`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2011/01/20/how-to-get-razor-intellisense-for-model-in-a-class-library-project.aspx)):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <system.web.webPages.razor>
        <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web.webPages.razor>

    <system.web>
        <compilation targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but as I used the MVC 4 template that is already there (not exactly the same, but equal and as generated by the template it should be correct).

Answer (score 0):

Ive done a similar thing using MEF to create plug ins. Make sure you add a using statememnt for 'system.web.mvc' and 'system.web.mvc.html'

Think there the right ones... Not got solution to check

Here you go:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
@using System.Web.Mvc;
@model Terminals.Models.vmDeviceAdd
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Terminals/Views/Shared/Master/_TerminalLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but as I used the MVC 4 template that is already there.

Comment: Ok, but I didnt mean in the web config I meant in the actual view. Is that there and just omitted from your code example?

Comment: I do not understand what exactly you mean - can you give me an example?